# Git Merge with conflicts - Shows all files as mine

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

When I am doing a git merge with conflicts, I faced a small issue. Once I merge master into my feature branch let's say there are 10 files that came from a previous commit by someone else and two files conflict with mine.

Then, I fixed the conflicts and commit and push all the changes. When I check the commit details, all 10 files were modified by me though I have changed only two files. Is this the default behaviour of Git? I am doing this merge and push using Visual Studio IDE and Source Tree. I am not using any commands.

Here is a small video in YT that is what I am doing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziQlAo8H5w8&ab_channel=TroubleChute

Comment: You changed them in the merge. A automatic merge is still a merge which requires changing the files. Whether the merge conflicted or not is irrelevant.

Comment: The merge *you did* has indeed changed the files. Expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The merge itself edited the files and you will therefore be written as the latest editor when committing/pushing